# How can i tell if i'm being called during DLL_PROCESS_DETACH after ExitProcess has been called?

Tags: delphi, winapi, dll, process, delphi-5

i have a unit in Delphi that (has the option) to provide a single global object:

```
var
   InternalThemeParkServices: TThemeParkServices;

function ThemeParkServices: TThemeParkServices;
begin
   if InternalThemeParkServices= nil then
      InternalThemeParkServices := TThemeParkServices.Create();
   Result := InternalThemeParkServices ;
end;

...

initialization
finalization
   FreeAndNil(InternalThemeServices);
end.
```

And i destroy myself during process shutdown.

> **Note**: Another code variant is:
>
> ```
> var
>    InternalThemeParkServices: IThemeParkServices;
>
> function ThemeParkServices: TThemeParkServices;
> begin
>    if InternalThemeParkServices= nil then
>       InternalThemeParkServices := TThemeParkServices.Create();
>    Result := InternalThemeParkServices ;
> end;
> ```
>
> Where the interface variable is implicitly destroyed when it's
>   reference count goes to zero during program shutdown

When my object is no longer used (i.e. during its `destructor`), i call call various WinAPI functions.

The problem is that if someone uses my class from a DLL (something which i cannot control), then anything being called during:

```
finalization
```

is the Delphi moral equivalent of [`DLL_PROCESS_DETACH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). [There](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/01/05/10253268.aspx) are [all kinds of things](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/04/27/10298256.aspx) i [should not be doing during](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=63509) `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` [when the process is terminating](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/01/15/9948740.aspx) (e.g. `CoCreateInstance`).

i know Embarcadero uses:

```
initialization 
   if not IsLibrary then
   begin
      ...
```

Which i perhaps i could adapt, changing my code from:

```
var
   InternalThemeParkServices: IThemeParkServices;
```

(using implicit cleanup), to:

```
var
   InternalThemeParkServices: IThemeParkServices;
...
finalization
   if IsLibrary then
      Pointer(InternalThemeParkServices) := nil; //defeat reference counting and let the object leak
end;
```

and let it leak.

But is this the best resolution? i *assume* it means that if the dll running my code is unloaded (but not during process shutdown) that i'll leak memory. If the dll is attached and detached, i'll leak each time.

What i *really* want is Delphi to run its `finalization` blocks *before* `ExitProcess`/`DllMain(DLL_PROCESS_DETACH)`. Is this possible?

### Bonus Chatter

[@pa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/30447/pa) deciphered [the Delphi application shutdown scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1185236/12597):

> The hierarchy of shutdown is as follows
>
> ```
>   Application.Terminate()
>     performs some unidentified housekeeping of application
>     calls Halt()
>
>   Halt()
>     calls ExitProc if set
>     alerts the user in case of runtime error
>     get rid of PackageLoad call contexts that might be pending
>     finalize all units
>     clear all exception handlers
>     call ExitprocessProc if set
>     and finally, call ExitProcess() from 'kernel32.dll'
>
>   ExitProcess() 
>     unloads all DLLs
>     uses TerminateProcess() to kill the process
> ```

With DLLs being unloaded *after* a call to `ExitProcess` - because Windows is the one who does it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To tell if you're being called during DLL_PROCESS_DETACH after ExitProcess has been called, you can write initialization code for your library so that your code is executed when `FreeLibrary` is called from the main program. The 'lpReserved' parameter will be '1' if `ExitProcess` have already been called, '0' otherwise:

```
..
var
  SaveDllProcEx: TDllProcEx;

procedure DllMainEx(Reason: Integer; Reserved: Integer);
begin
  if (Reason = DLL_PROCESS_DETACH) and (Reserved = 0) then
    // Main app is still running, cleanup.

  if Assigned(SaveDllProcEx) then
    SaveDllProcEx(Reason, Reserved);
end;

initialization

if IsLibrary then begin
  SaveDllProcEx := DllProcEx;
  DllProcEx := @DllMainEx;
end;
```

From [DllMain entry point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The lpReserved parameter indicates whether the DLL is being unloaded
>   as a result of a FreeLibrary call, a failure to load, or process
>   termination.

Comment: Problem is that my isn't in a library, it's in a unit. Someone else might turn around and use my code in their unit. Someone else might turn around and use *that* code in their unit. Then someone might use *that* unit in a DLL. Strictly speaking a `TBase64` class is not *in* a dll, it's a helper class in a code file, the same way `TStringList` is not in a dll. But now `TBase64`, `TStringList`, and `TThemeParkServices` must defend against being called from a dll.

Comment: @Ian - You can test in unit initialization if you're in a library, and if you are, save the original DllProcEx then assign it to your function. In your 'DllMain' function, call saved DllProcEx if it is not nil. This way you can preserve initialization code chain. Otherwise I don't see any problem.

Comment: Update your code sample to do that instead, and you'll steal yourself an accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

> What I *really* want is Delphi to run its `finalization` blocks before `DllMain(DLL_PROCESS_DETACH)`. Is this possible?

No it is not possible.

If you need to perform shutdown actions that cannot be done during `DllMain(DLL_PROCESS_DETACH)` then you will need to add an exported function to your DLL that peforms the finalization. You should then require your DLL's clients to call this function before unloading the DLL. This is the same pattern as `CoInitialize`/`CoUninitialize`.

Comment: It sucks that a person using a unit, using a unit, using a unit, needs to have that implementation detail's implementation detail's implementation detail leaked. Especially when the likelyhood is that nobody will ever call the code from a dll.